# Getting IndexError: list index out of range error

Tags: python, amazon-cognito, aws-cdk, aws-userpools

I have created "**CfnUserPool**" object using https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_cognito/CfnUserPool.html aws document.

I wanted to fetch "**Pool Id**" of UserPool. It's Id value is - "**us-east-1_4kXXXXXXX**". I tried so many options to fetch this value using python but it didn't work.

So I fetched "**Pool ARN**" value of UserPool, because it has id value in it.
Pool ARN is - "**arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:userpool/us-east-1_4kXXXXXXX**"
You can see there is "us-east-1_4kXXXXXXX" substring in Pool ARN.

I tried below code to get "us-east-1_4kXXXXXXX" value from Pool ARN -

```
_cognito_user_pool = _cognito.CfnUserPool(stack, id="pool-id", user_pool_name="user-auth-pool")
_user_pool_id = _cognito_user_pool.attr_arn.split('/')[1]
```

I was getting "IndexError: list index out of range" error.

I tried to print this ARN value on console and I got this value - **${Token[TOKEN.327]}**
I don't know why it's printing User pool arn value is in Token format. I think whenever I am trying to fetch it, it is in Token format and that is why I am not able to split it by "/".
When we pass ARN value to any resource, it goes in proper format or string format and not in Token format. But if we try to manipulate it, it gives **"IndexError: list index out of range" error.** since it in token format.

Comment: can you please share the value of '_cognito_user_pool'

Comment: @AdamStrauss - When I am trying to print arn value it shows - ${Token[TOKEN.327]}

Comment: I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Answer - 
I have resolved this issue by using **UserPool** instead of **CfnUserPool**.
**UserPool** has "**user_pool_id**" attribute and we can fetch it's id value using this attribute.